# How to put json response in loop with condition?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I have parsed json response and saved it using .findAll(). What I want to do is, ignore keyframeId if value is '-1' else put keyframeId in .get() request with loop. I did some code but the value doesnt set in get() request and gives 'KO'. Here it takes all the values in Vector and place all in single http call see error for details. Also I am not sure about the doIf condition. Can you please help? Thanks.
My Json response format is like this.

```
{
totalCount: 1134,
limit: 9,
offset: 0,
resources: [
        {
        title: "Test",
        keyframeId: -1
        }
        {
        title: "Test1",
        keyframeId: 12345
        }
        {
        title: "Test2",
        keyframeId: 12341
        }
        {
        title: "Test3",
        keyframeId: -1
        }
        {
        title: "Test4",
        keyframeId: 135481
        }
        ....
        ....
]}
```

Here is the gatling script,

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class MamamSearch extends Simulation {

    val testServerUrl = System.getProperty("testServerUrl", "https://someurl")
    val username = System.getProperty("username", "ma")
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "ma")
    val userCount = Integer.getInteger("userCount", 1).toInt

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL(testServerUrl)
        .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control" -> "max-age=0",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

    val headers_2 = Map("Accept" -> "text/css,*/*;q=0.1")

    val headers_6 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Cache-Control" -> "max-age=0",
        "Origin" -> testServerUrl,
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

    val headers_80 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

    val headers_7 = Map("Accept" -> "image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8")

    val headers_11 = Map("Origin" -> testServerUrl)

    val headers_12 = Map(
        "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
        "If-Modified-Since" -> "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
        "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
        "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

    val headers_15 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
        "If-Modified-Since" -> "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
        "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
        "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

    val headers_16 = Map("Accept" -> "*/*")

    val headers_18 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html",
        "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
        "If-Modified-Since" -> "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
        "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
        "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

    val headers_19 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Origin" -> testServerUrl)

    val headers_27 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Content-type" -> "text/plain",
        "Origin" -> testServerUrl)

    val uri1 = testServerUrl + "/mamam"
    val uri2 = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0"

    // Login request
    val scn = scenario("MamamSearch")
        .exec(http("Login")
            .post("/mamam/a/masteraccount/login")
            .headers(headers_6)
            .formParam("username", username)
            .formParam("password", password))


    //  Fetch and save data
    .exec(http("Keyframe_request")
            .get(uri1 + "/awsset/browse%3Bresource_type=media%3Boffset=1%3Blimit=9")
            .headers(headers_12)
            .check(jsonPath("$.resources[*].keyframeId").findAll.saveAs("kList"))
            )

    // added loop and conditions
    .doIf(session => session("Keyframe_request").validate[String].map(kList => !kList.contains("-1")))
    {
        foreach("${kList}", "keyId") {
            exec(http("Set_Keyframes")
                .get(uri1 + "/keyframes/${kList};width=185;height=103")
                .headers(headers_7))
        }       
    }   

    .exec(http("Logout")
        .get("/mam/logout")
        .headers(headers_80))       

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Throws following Error:

```
21345 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] WARN  i.g.http.ahc.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'Set_Keyframes' failed: status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 400
21346 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] DEBUG i.g.http.ahc.AsyncHandlerActor - 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Request:
Set_Keyframes: KO status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 400

21390 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  io.gatling.http.ahc.HttpEngine - Sending request=Set_Keyframes uri=https://someurl/mamam/keyframes/Vector(167154,%20167035,%20167037,%20167040,%20167029,%20167024,%20167026,%20167022,%20167023);width=185;height=103:
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to take a value from the response and then use it within the next request. Firstly you must save the correct keyframeId.

What was not clear was whether you wanted to select a random keyframeId from your list or multiple keyframes, I have opted to select a random one.

First is that we must apply some jsonPath to our JSON response. This code `.check(jsonPath("$.resources[?(@.keyframeId > -1)].keyframeId")` will return only a list of keyframeIds which are greater than -1.

Next we select a random one and save it to a variable.

```
//  Fetch and save data
.exec(http("Keyframe_request")
  .get(uri1 + "/awsset/browse%3Bresource_type=media%3Boffset=1%3Blimit=9")
  .headers(headers_12)
  .check(jsonPath("$.resources[?(@.keyframeId > -1)].keyframeId")
      .ofType[String]
      .findAll
      .transform(s => util.Random.shuffle(s).apply(1))
      .saveAs("keyframeId"))
```

Now you just need to check to see if the session variable keyframeId exists and use it to drive your response using `${keyframeId}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.foreach("${IdList}", "id") {
            doIf(session => session("id").as[String] != "-1") {
            exec(http("ID != -1").get(session => session("id").as[String])
            .check(status.is(404)))}
            }
```